# How can I manage my store cards on the Android?

Tags: applications, barcode

I have a bunch of store cards with barcodes on them hanging on my keychain. Every now and then I won't have my keys when I'm in the store. I once saw someone with an iPhone who had an app that managed those bar codes. Is there anything similar for the droid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used it but I remember reading about [Key Ring Rewards Cards](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.froogloid.kring.google.zxing.client.android&feature=search_result).  Try that and see what you think.

*Edit:* I also tried searching the market for "loyalty cards" and came up with [this list of apps](https://market.android.com/search?q=loyalty%20cards&c=apps). I was going to specifically name some but as I haven't tried them I thought it best that I just give you the list. Seems there are quite a few that will help you manage your cards

Comment: My wife uses Key Ring with mixed success. Not all of the barcode readers can manage the screen, and sometimes the Droid is just to big to fit where they want you to put the little keyring card.